# Obtain timezone of a Google Analytics 4 property?

Tags: timezone, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

There doesn't seem to be a way to obtain the timezone of a Google Analytics property, or is there?

The Data API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema?hl=en) returns data in the property's timezone but in order for us to interpret it correctly we need to know what timezone the property is in.

Has anyone found a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Data API is for reporting purpose only.

For property and other GA related configurations, `Admin API` should be used.
Here is the [property.get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/get) method, the response of which has `timeZone` in it.

Answer (score 1):

The Data API responses now contain a metadata object with `"currencyCode"` and `"timeZone"` strings. This is a part of an example response:

[image: metadata-with-currencyCode-and-timeZone]

More documentation on these fields will come out soon, and these fields will be available in the client libraries (i.e. python) soon.

Thanks, Brett

The Google Analytics Team

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the Data API response metadata, it is possible to use the Admin API [properties.get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/get) method to obtain the [property's timezone](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties#Property.FIELDS.time_zone).